# A Riddle: The 8th Empire

Tags: riddle, wordplay

You start with something you are,

a dog, a plant or driving a car.

Then close one eye after the versus,

the odd one in aeon must be minused.

The answer should be a number in system of eight,

You'll get it after you remove the head of the gate.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> **54**

*You start with something you are,*
*a dog, a plant or driving a car.*

> Start with the word '**LIVING**', which *you are*, as are both a dog and a plant, and considering you might 'feel alive' or 'be truly living' while driving a car at speed...

*Then close one eye after the versus,*

> Remove the I ('eye') which is *after* the V ('versus'): **LIVNG**

*the odd one in aeon must be minused.*

> Remove the N (the only consonant in 'AEON'): **LIVG**

*The answer should be a number in system of eight,*
*You'll get it after you remove the head of the gate.*

> Remove the G, the first letter ('head') of 'GATE': **LIV**
>
>  What we are left with is the number **54** expressed in Roman numerals (a 'system of 8': I, V, X, L, C, D, M and Nulla). The use of Roman numerals also explains the allusion to 'Empire' in the title.

Comment: You're very close.:) re-evaluate "driving a car" portion of the riddle to get the exact starting word. The title itself provides 2 clues.

Comment: @coredump Aha, I think I've got it now! :)

Comment: Woot! :) You have an alternative interpretation of "system of 8" that works, too. Original intent is that "empire" and "8th" are 2 separate clues/transformation.